# How do I return a criteria after summing up values based on the criteria given?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that looks similar to this:

[image]

So column A and column B are combined along with a number in column C. What I am trying to do is add up each value in each column (for example: add each C column for each time "Cat" appears, and "Dog" and "Grass", etc) and then find the value in columns A and B that is the highest, and return that value. So for example, in my example above, Dog would be the formula result because it's C column totals to 28. Is there a formula (or, most likely, a combination of formulas) that can accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered a pivot table?

Comment: I have, unfortunately for the purposes of the project I am working on it does have to be a formula (or, like I said, a combination of formulas). Thank you though!

Comment: vba will probably be best here unless you have access to the new dynamic array formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to show, the formula would be:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($1:$24)=MATCH(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),0),ROW($1:$24)*{1,1}))))),MATCH(MAX(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,INDEX(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($1:$24)=MATCH(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),0),ROW($1:$24)*{1,1}))))))+SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,INDEX(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($1:$24)=MATCH(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),0),ROW($1:$24)*{1,1}))))))),SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,INDEX(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($1:$24)=MATCH(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),0),ROW($1:$24)*{1,1}))))))+SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,INDEX(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($1:$24)=MATCH(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT((ROW($1:$24)-1)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD((ROW($1:$24)-1),2)+1))),0),ROW($1:$24)*{1,1})))))),0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

It gets a little more manageable with the new dynamic array formulas:

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(SEQUENCE(24,,0),2)+1)))),MATCH(MAX(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,UNIQUE(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(SEQUENCE(24,,0),2)+1)))))+SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,UNIQUE(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(SEQUENCE(24,,0),2)+1)))))),SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,UNIQUE(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(SEQUENCE(24,,0),2)+1)))))+SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,UNIQUE(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(SEQUENCE(24,,0),2)+1))))),0))
```

[image]

---

But we can use helper columns with the dynamic array formula.

In one cell we put:

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX(A1:B12,N(IF({1},INT(SEQUENCE(24,,0)/2)+1)),N(IF({1},MOD(SEQUENCE(24,,0),2)+1))))
```

I put it in E1, then I refer to that with the sumifs:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E1#)+SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,E1#)
```

I put that in F1, then use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(E1#,MATCH(MAX(F1#),F1#,0))
```

[image]

---

Doing it the long way with normal formulas, one would need to copy paste the two columns one below the other and use Remove duplicate on the data tab to get a unique list:

[image]

Then use the formula in F1:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,E1)+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,E1)
```

And copy down the list.  then use the INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(MAX(F:F),F:F,0))
```

to return the desired value.

[image]

---

And just to be thorough here is why vba is better for this.  Put this in a module:

```
Function myMatch(RngA As Range, RngB As Range, sumRng As Range)
    If RngA.Cells.Count <> RngB.Cells.Count Or RngA.Cells.Count <> sumRng.Cells.Count Or RngB.Cells.Count <> sumRng.Cells.Count Then
        myMatch = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim arrA As Variant
    arrA = RngA.Value

    Dim arrB As Variant
    arrB = RngB

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To 2
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
            Dim uRec As String
            uRec = IIf(j = 1, arrA(i, 1), arrB(i, 1))

            Dim smRec As Double
            smRec = Application.SumIfs(sumRng, RngA, IIf(j = 1, arrA(i, 1), arrB(i, 1))) + Application.SumIfs(sumRng, RngB, IIf(j = 1, arrA(i, 1), arrB(i, 1)))
            On Error Resume Next
                dict.Add uRec, smRec
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    Next j

    Dim mx As Double
    mx = 0

    Dim temp As String
    temp = ""

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        If dict(key) > mx Then
            temp = key
            mx = dict(key)
        End If
    Next key

    myMatch = temp
End Function
```

Then all you need to do on the worksheet is call it as a normal function listing the three areas:

```
=myMatch(A1:A12,B1:B12,C1:C12)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the help! I am very new to VBA so I apologize for any stupid questions but - I'm getting the following error when entering that code - "Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")"

Comment: Where are you putting the code?  Hit Alt-F11, then add a module and put the code in there.

Comment: My apologies, it does work in Excel! The issue is - I need to be able to import the same functionality to Google Sheets. Is there a way to get the same result there? Importing the same code gives me the above error. I apologize for not being more clear.

Comment: @Falcon4ch you asked for Excel.  The answer for Google sheets would be totally different and not transferable.  Neither the formula or the code approach will work in google sheets.  if you want a google sheet answer re ask your question with the correct tags.  There is no way to do this that is compatible with both.

Comment: I see. Well that will make things a lot more difficult. In any case, I really appreciate your time on this! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also solved the case using **Power Query**.

Steps are:

1. Add your source data (which is the three column table) to the Power Query Editor;

[image: Step1]

2. Use **Merge Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to merge the first two columns by a delimiter, say semicolon `;`;

[image: Step 2]

3. Use **Split Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to split the merged column by the same delimiter, say semicolon `;`, and make sure in the *Advanced Options* choose to put the results into **Rows**;

[image: Split Columns]

4. Use **Group By** function to group the last column by the `Merged` column and set `SUM` as the function;

[image: Step 4]

5. Lastly, **sort** the last column *Descending*.

[image: Step 5]

You can **Close & Load** the result to a new worksheet (by default).

Here are the **Power Query M Codes** behind the scene for your reference only. All steps are using built-in functions which are straight forward and easy to execute.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns", {{"Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Merged"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Merged"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Column3]), type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Sum", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)